# Most convenient way to generate unique random hash for a column in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `foo` with a non-nullable and unique column called `hash`. I would like to create a trigger, or default to this column if possible, that generates a unique random 64-character string.

Although it is possible to create a default like such, it does not prevent the low chance of generating a non-unique hash.

`alter TABLE foo ADD column register_key text UNIQUE NOT NULL default md5(random()::text);`

I am working on creating a trigger in plpgsql but am struggling to compare the hash I generated.

Here is what I attempted to do, I created a function that returns a trigger that would generate the hash

```
create or replace function generate_hash() returns trigger
as $$
declare temp_hash text;
        counter int;
begin
    while exists(select * from foo where hash = temp_hash) and counter < 10 loop
            select substr(sha512(random()::text), 0, 64) into temp_hash;
            counter := counter + 1;
    end loop;
    if counter >= 10 
       then RAISE EXCEPTION 'cannot generate hash';
       end if;
    new.hash = temp_hash;
    return new;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

and created a trigger on table `foo`

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_hash
BEFORE INSERT ON foo
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE generate_hash();
```

When I tested this by inserting a new record, I receive the error `ERROR: null value in column "hash" violates not-null constraint`.

What did I do wrong? Is there a more appropriate approach than what I am doing?

Comment: There is no point storing a "random hash" (i.e. a hash of a random number) - you may as well just store the random number directly. So why are you doing this?

Comment: `CREATE TRIGGER insert_hash FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE generate_hash();` <-- This trigger will utterly wreck your runtime performance - think about what happens if `TABLE foo` contains over 1m rows... every `INSERT` will essentially scan and rewrite the entire table.

Comment: You are right on that there may be no point in using the sha512 method, my main goal is to generate a 64-character long string, and the method I used gets that done. I would be happy to hear if there are better options.

Comment: I'd like to know why you want to generate a 64-char random string in the first place.

Comment: @dai It was to act as a unique identifier other than the id column

Comment: ...why do you want that? What's wrong with good ol' `GENERATED AS IDENTITY` or a GUID value?

Comment: It sounds like you really want a GUID (globally unique identifier) not a hash (digest of some buffer)?

Comment: @dai Was asked to do this by my senior.

Comment: Then ask them why a hash not a GUID, and why not just an un-hashed ID?  Seniors make mistakes too.

Comment: @Rico Whenever you're asked to do something for work, by a client or your boss or whatever, you're expected to _ask questions back_ and find out the "whys?" - accepting orders without question is unwise - this is all part of software-engineering: _gathering requirements_ and acting in the best-interests of the client.

Comment: "Please drop all tables and erase the backups."  -- just say no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since data is inserted one row at a time, you could use a timestamp as value for your hash, as:

```
alter TABLE foo ADD column register_key varchar(64) 
UNIQUE NOT NULL default encode(digest(now()::text, 'sha256'), 'hex');
```

Comment: What would happen in the slight chance that the same hash is generated?

Comment: Every insert has its own time, however the probability that a hash will be duplicated is not zero, it is close enough to zero to be negligible. To be completely sure it would be necessary to enclose insertion operations in try catch (similar depending on language) blocks to repeat the operation in case of failure.